# MVC -> Binding to Collections of Custom Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, model-binding, auto-populating

Property, from which of set of hidden fields are to be populated:

```
public abstract class MyPageView
{        
    [UIHint("List")]
    public IEnumerable<IOption> OptionList { get; set; }
}
```

Command to do so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OptionList)
```

Implementation of defined 'List' template:

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomWanted.FlatShare.Services.ViewModels.Options.IOption>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{    
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ToList()[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ToList()[i].Name)
}
```

What I GET generated:

```
<input id="OptionList__0__Id" name="OptionList.[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="OptionList__0__Name" name="OptionList.[0].Name" type="hidden" value="New York" />
```

What I NEED TO GET generated, so that model binding works correctly:

```
<input id="OptionList_0__Id" name="OptionList[0].Id" type="hidden" value="5"></input>
<input id="OptionList_0__Name" name="OptionList[0].Name" type="hidden" value="New York"></input>
```

Any Ideas on how to get rid of that **dot** so i have `OptionList[0].Id` instead of `OptionList.[0].Id` ?

Cheers.

Comment: I never had a reason to save collections of hidden input fields. What is your reason to do that?

Comment: Apart from populating  hidden input fields i am actually populating <select> element using helper Html.DropDownListFor() and that one won't bind back to my IEnumerable<IOption> model automatically. That's why.

Comment: Actual purpose is that i want to write an custom server-side validator for `IEnumerable<IOption> OptionList` so i need the data to be bound back to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IList<IOption>` or `IOption[]` instead:

```
public abstract class MyPageView
{        
    [UIHint("List")]
    public IList<IOption> OptionList { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@model IList<RoomWanted.FlatShare.Services.ViewModels.Options.IOption>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Name)
}
```

Comment: this would work if i would be using it directly in view as you are showing. but i am using in my main view `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OptionList)` (as there are more lists than just one) and those commands are using 'List' template. Maybe somebody some other way how to achieve fuctionality without loosing the flexibility of the soultion ? but thanks anyway for your post.